# Why did Listz and Hanon use the word "transcendent" to describe piano exercises?

Tags: piano, terminology

The middle set of piano exercises by Hanon is described as "transcendent".

> ['Transcendent Exercises for Preparing the Fingers for the Virtuoso Exercises.
>
>   Practise the exercises in Part II, like those in Part I, with the metronome at 60; similarly practise all the following piano exercises where the tempo is not indicated, and gradually'...](https://www.hanon-online.com/)

Franz Liszt wrote "Transcendental Etudes". Having grown up in the era of Transcendental Meditation I find this an unusual use of the word. Does anybody know what they intended by it?

Comment: The Liszt might be better translated as "transcendent" (see https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/transcendent 1.1) to match the French title: "Études d'exécution transcendante''). Hanon wasn't a piano teacher but a marketing guy, so in his case it didn't matter what the word meant so long as you bought the product!

Answer (score 1):

The German [wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tudes_d%E2%80%99ex%C3%A9cution_transcendante) offers the explanation, that Liszt used this term as an ironic reaction to a statement by Fétis, that Liszt could be considered as eminent representative of a school, which came to an end, but without founding a new school [my translation].

Considering, that Latin *transcendere* simply means to leave one thing and move to another, its meaning is not so exclusive as the word sounds and could be simply replaced by something like *exceeding* (which would also easily be applied to the difficulty).